# Angular test - Failed: Cannot destructure property 'xxx' of 'undefined' as it is undefined

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, ngrx

I try the first time to write an angular test.

I just want to run this test without any errors

```
 fit('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
      });
```

But all time I get error

***CodingListComponent> should create***

> Failed: Cannot destructure property 'coding' of 'undefined' as
> it is undefined.

Only where I use this '**coding**' is in selector, but don't know what I do wrong.

In Karma runner I get table with data and col/rows, data and table are loaded correctly.

If someone can point me to the right direction?

Thnx in advice

I have component with material table where I show list of all items.

component.ts - simplified version

```
    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private store: Store<fromStore.State>,
        private router: Router,
        private matDialog: MatDialog,
        private dialogService: DialogService
      ) {
        this.coding$ = this.store.pipe(
          select(fromStore.codingSelectors.getCoding)
        );
    
        this.loading$ = this.store.pipe(
          select(fromStore.codingSelectors.getCodingLoading)
        );
    
        this.size$ = this.store.pipe(
          select(fromStore.codingSelectors.getCodingSize)
        );
    
       ...
}
```

Here is my selector

```
export const getCodingData = createSelector(
  getState,
  ({ coding }) => coding?.data \\ ---------> only here I use this
);

    export const getCoding = createSelector(
      getCodingData,
      data => data && data?.content
    );
    
    export const getCodingLoading = createSelector(
      getState,
      ({ code}) => code.loading
    );
    
    export const getCodingSize = createSelector(
      getCodingData ,
      data => data && data.size
    );
```

And here is my test file

```
fdescribe('CodingListComponent', () => {

  let store: MockStore;
  let component: CodingListComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CodingListComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        CodingListComponent, 
        PanelComponent, 
        FiltersComponent, 
        SearchBarComponent],

      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        SharedModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: MatDialog, useValue: {} },
        provideMockStore<fromStore.State>({
          selectors: [
            {
              selector: getCodings, value: [
                {
                  "coded": false
                  "codedBy": null,
                  "codedAt": null
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
        }),
      ]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MedicalCodingListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);

  }));


  afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
  });

  fit('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For a quick debug, try this:

```
export const getCodingData = createSelector(
  getState,
  data => {
    console.log({ data }); // You will see undefined here
    return data;
  }
);
```

In your testing environment, somehow that selector returns undefined. You have to figure out why this is and it is most likely a bad configuration with regards to `provideMockStore`.

Comment: Hi, thnx for answer. My selector first time retun NULL, and half second after they return data